# Como autocompletar campos de un formulario

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

mi pregunta es la siguiente, tengo un formulario para ingresar datos de un empleado (numero de control, nombre, edad) como puedo hacer para que al ingresar el numero de control si es igual que algun numero de control que tengo registrado en la base de datos me autocomplete los datos faltantes de el formulario

la tabla de mi base de datos se llama general

este es el codigo de mi archivo nuevo_registro.php

de antemano muchas gracias

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="registrar_tablas.php">
        <label for="">Personal De Salud</label> <br>
        <select name="personal_salud" id="personalsalud">
  <option value=""></option>
  <option value="enfermera1">Enfermera 1</option>
  <option value="enfermera2">Enfermera 2</option>
        </select> <br><br>
    
    <label for="">Num Control</label> <br>
    <input type="text">
    <br>
    
    <label for="">Nombre</label> <br>
    <input type="text">
    <br>
    
    <label for="">edad</label> <br>
    <input type="text">
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: ¿que has investigado? Debes poner lo que has investigado y el código que te da error (ahora mismo no hay ningun error!) para que podamos ayudarte. Como orientación te recomiendo el uso de jquery y jqueryui, que tiene una funcion [autocomplete](https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/). Léete [ask], [tour] y [example] para aprender mejor el funcionamiento del sitio, gracias.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes crear datalist el cual debe tener una ID, luego al textbox en su atributo "list" pones la ID del datalist. Demo:

```html
<datalist id="Nums_controls">
  <option value="número de control 1">
  <option value="número de control 2">
  <option value="número de control 3">
  <option value="número de control 4">
  <option value="número de control 5">
</datalist>
<form action="registrar_tablas.php">
        <label for="">Personal De Salud</label> <br>
        <select name="personal_salud" id="personalsalud">
  <option value=""></option>
  <option value="enfermera1">Enfermera 1</option>
  <option value="enfermera2">Enfermera 2</option>
        </select> <br><br>
    
    <label for="">Num Control</label> <br>
    <input type="text" list="Nums_controls">
    <br>
    
    <label for="">Nombre</label> <br>
    <input type="text">
    <br>
    
    <label for="">edad</label> <br>
    <input type="text">
 </form>
```